# .htaccess prevent access from all but root (with or without trailing slash)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My approach is - deny everything except what I'm familiar with.

I want to allow access to `root`, `index.php` and `familiar 'safe' extensions`.

Thus I won't have to THINK about what I should protect, but rather what I shouldn't.

This is how my .htaccess file looks:

```
# Disable files and directories index listing
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Deny all files.
<FilesMatch ".">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Except index.php
<FilesMatch "index.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

# Except root
<FilesMatch "^$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

# And except familiar extensions
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|jpe?g|png|gif)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Everything works perfectly except when I try to access the address without a trailing slash: `http://localhost/site` instead of `http://localhost/site/`, 
then I get the 'Forbidden' error page.

Would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by denying access only to files that contain a dot `.`:

```
# Deny all files.
<FilesMatch "\.">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 5):

Reply to an old post but in case someone else wanders in here, you could modify your FilesMatch as follows:

```
<FilesMatch "^(/)?$">
```

This matches the location's root with or without a trailing slash.